# Wordpress submenu hover

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, hover

http://equilibrarte.pt/onworking/?csspreview=true#settingsdiv

this is my site my main problem is that i can't change the hover settings inside of the submenu in serviços, i tried like .

```
#menu-main-menu .submenu ul li { 
color: #000000;
}


#menu-main-menu ul ul li ul {
color: #000000;
}
```

My main issue is that i can't even with JETPACK change the css settings, in bootstrap i did all the things to the other links and it worked perfectly but now this is being the biggest problem.

Comment: Use Firebug or another browser html Dev tool, find out the exact hierarchy and also if using a plugin that will play with the CSS, use !important in your declarations so width: 100px. Important; etc.

Comment: that's what i did before came here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all `a` are being targeted to change to white on `hover`

addd this to your code:

```
#navigation .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu li a:hover{color: #000000 !important;}
```

Comment: that changed me also the menu :\ i just wanted to change the submenu hover only the items inside of submenu